# How to serialize object correctly in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have nested complex object in my controller:

```
class ClientDTO {
public InnerClass cl;

public getCl()...
public setCl()...
}
```

InnerClass contains some primitive data types Integer,String.

My controller just returns this ClientDTO.
On my thymeleaf template I've got :

```
var client=[[${client}]]
```

Here client is a ClientDTO value, returned from the controller.
This variable client is serialized into *ru.foo.ClientDTO@6543785*
which is incorrect.

How can I fix it to receive correct *client* object in form of json like this: `ClientDTO{cl: {....}}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say where exactly you want this based on your description, but I am assuming your `var` definition is in a script tag. If so, use

`<script data-th-inline="javascript">`

to make thymeleaf properly create the variable. Secondly, wrap `client` like this:

`var client = /*[[${client}]]*/ {};`

to ensure there is a default and preserve natural templating, with the default being `{}` or `''` or such. From there you can convert to json if you wish.